# How do I change the colors of the boxplots when overlaying them in Matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization

As you can see the code below generates an image of 5 different graphs, each having their own 13 boxplots where 3 are distributed on the same vertical as each other for 4 verticals (and 1 standalone) per plot. I want this format, but I would like to change the colors and add a legend so you can identify which plot belongs to which. How should I set the color so there are 3 different colors on each plot? Is there a way to add a legend corresponding to those colors too?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,5, squeeze=True,sharey=False, sharex=True, figsize=(15,10)) # Create 1x5 plots
fig.tight_layout()

for i in range(len(continuous_variables)):
    for j in range(len(discrete_variables)):
        x_vals = combined_df[discrete_variables[j]].unique().tolist()
        x_vals.sort()
        y_vals = []
        for x in x_vals:
            y = combined_df[continuous_variables[i]][(combined_df[discrete_variables[j]] == x)].tolist()
            y_vals.append(y)
        axs[i].boxplot(y_vals, labels=x_vals)
```

[image: Image of the boxplots overlayed]

Comment: my 2 cents: these overlaid box plots will be hard to read even with different colors

Comment: Yeah, I also have this expanded as a 3x5 subplot grid but I wanted to also have a version where they're compressed because they're not very easy to compare across rows either.

Comment: Maybe you would like to consider asymmetric violin plots? It would provide both readability and a more detailed insight into the data.

Comment: Interesting @GuillaumeAnsanay-Alex I don't think I can implement asymmetric violin plots, but I do think these boxplots would be more readable if they were symmetric violin plots stacked on top of each other instead. I just did that and I think it's at least somewhat an improvement.

Comment: @Sameer Why aren't you able to implement asymmetric violin plots?

Comment: @KristianCanler I'm not sure if you can use an asymmetric violin plot when comparing distributions of more than 2 metrics at once. I would be comparing at the very least 3 at once so I think just layering violin plots on top of each other is the best I can do.

Comment: @Sameer Quite right. I can't imagine a case where this is going to be remotely readable. I don't think implimentation is your main problem here.

Comment: @KristianCanler yeah I ended up going with just violin plots placed adjacently around each category instead of stacked on each other and color coded